# Ne forlasu rilatan KI-vorton

Tags: grammar

Laŭ [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/ti-forlaso.html#i-zvl) ni havas:

1) Ĝusta: *La viro, kiun mi vidis, portis valizon.*

2) Malĝusta: **La viro, mi vidis, portis valizon.**

La dua frazo estas malĝusta se ĝi celas la saman sencon ol la unua. Mia demando estas ĉu la dua frazo estus ĝusta, se la celo ne estus *kiun* mi vidis, sed *kion* mi vidis, kvazaŭ temus pri parenteza rimarko laŭ la jena frazo: *La viro (mi vidis/mi konstatis) portis valizon.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mi iom detale diskutis tiajn aferon kun Bertilo en majo. Pli precize, ni diskutis la frazon **Kion vi pensas ke signifas "paradizas"?** Kial estas "ke" en tiu frazo? Ĉu ĝi povas esti *Kion, vi pensas, signifas "paradizas"?*?

Mi pensas ke via frazo estas formo de la jena:

- Mi vidis ke la viro portas valizon.

Ĉu vere eblas forigi "ke" simple per ŝanĝado de la vortordo? Ne estas tuje evidente. Eblas argumenti ke tio estas simpla apudmeto, kaj oni ja vidas tion de tempo al tempo.

- Ili havis viandon sur la fajro, ĉirkaŭ kiu, mi vidis, ili dancadis. (El Robinson Kruso)

Tia uzo ne estas ofta. Mi trovis nur du pliajn frazojn en la tekstaro kun "vidas"

- Ĉi tie, mi vidas, la pastroj estras kvazaŭ ĉe si
- Kaj vi, mi vidas, jam amikiĝis kun ŝi.

Jen Zamenhofa ekzemplo kun "pensas".

- Pri kio, vi pensas, mi tion diras? (El "La Gimnazio")

Mi iom miras ke tiaj frazoj estas tiel malloftaj, sed ili estas iom pli oftaj kun "pensas."

Kiam Bertilo diris ke oni ne diru "La viro, mi vidis, portis valizon", verŝajne li volis nur diri ke oni ne diru tion kun la signifo "la viro, kiun mi vidis..."

Cetere, laŭ Bertilo, ambaŭ frazoj estas ĝustaj:

- *Kion, vi pensas, signifas "paradizas"?*?
- *Kion vi pensas ke signifas "paradizas"?*?

Comment: Tre bona komento. Mi trovis tiun saman citaĵon el Robinsono Kruso en Tekstaro. Fakte mi preskaŭ uzis ĝin en mia demando por pravigi mian suspekton, sed finfine mi ne faris, por ne plilongigi la aferon. Mi ankaŭ samopinias ke Bertilo taksas malĝusta la frazon 2) nur se ĝi celas la sencon de la 1), tamen mi ne estis centprocente certa pri tio antaŭ ol Cyril Brosch konfirmis tion.

Comment: Via diskuto kun Bertilo pri tiuj du frazoj estas ege oportuna ĉi tie. Mi pensas ke temas pri du frazoj ligitaj inter si en unu sola frazo per du malsamaj rimedoj. Unuflanke, _Kion signifas "paradizas"?_. Aliflanke, _Kion vi pensas (pri tio)?_ Oni ligas ilin jen per uzo de parentezaj komoj, jen pere de _ke_. Laŭ mia kompreno, ambaŭ rimedoj donas la saman sencon.

Answer (score 3):

Jes, en la dua senco priskribita de vi la frazo 2) kompreneble estas ĝusta. Sed atentu, ke ankaŭ tie ne elfalis iu *kion*, ĉar relativa pronomo neniam povas ellasiĝi, sed ke temas pri enŝovita frazo en la frazo, kiel vi mem ĝuste analizis.

Comment: Kiel "kompreneble" ĝusta?

Comment: Ĉar parentezoj estas kutima afero en ĉiuj lingvoj kaj ne estas ia regulo en Esperanto, kiu iel limigus ilin. Tio koncernas la gramatikon. Mi ne volas taksi, ĉu la frazo estas stile rekomendinda.

Comment: Mi pensas ke la fakto ke Vidamuzo starigis la demandon, ke la respondo ne estas memevidenta.

Comment: Jes, pli `tion` ol `kion`: `... (tion mi vidis) ...`